# Asymptotic analysis of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know if the following relation is true and if we can prove it without using the equality between the sum of the series and $\ln (\sin t) - \ln t$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \sim -\ln{x}~~\text{when} ~~x\to 0$$

Thank you.

Comment: As x --> 0 the summand approaches $\ln 1$, so isn't it possible the series approaches 0?

Answer (score 0):

As $x \to 0$,

$$\log{\left ( 1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right )} \sim -\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2} $$

Thus, in that limit, the sum behaves as

$$-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} = -\frac{x^2}{6} $$